# Aiml files won't load in python

Tags: python, aiml

I've recently taken up aiml with python and I've tried the simplest program but even that seems to give me problems and I can't figure out why.

Here is the python script:

```
import aiml
kernel = aiml.Kernel()
kernel.learn("std-startup.xml")
kernel.respond("load aiml b")

while True:
    print (kernel.respond(raw_input("Enter your message >> ")))
```

Here is the contents of std-startup.xml:

```
<category>

    <pattern>
         LOAD AIML B
    </pattern>
    <template>
        <learn>basic-chat.aiml</learn>
    </template>

</category>
```

and here is the contents of basic-chat.aiml:

```
<category>
    <pattern>HELLO</pattern>
    <template>
        Well, hello!
    </template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>WHAT ARE YOU</pattern>
    <template>
        I'm a bot, silly!
    </template>
</category>
```

And I get this error WARNING: No match found for input: load aiml b.

I've seen a few people deal with them before and I've tried their solutions but nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance for any wisdom you have to offer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I got it to work, I scrapped the following line:

```
kernel.learn("std-startup.xml")
```

and replaced it with:

```
kernel.learn("basic-chat.aiml")
```

This loaded the basic-chat.aiml file and I received the desired output even though it will mean more lines of code in my python file

Answer (score 0):

Use input instead of raw_input in python 3 for python 2 raw_input will work.

Hope that help